# Program shuts down before if statement in C

Tags: c

The parameters do not run through the *if-statement* and I have no idea why.
For some context, this program is supposed to give you *"How many more years you have?"*, in consideration of your Continents estimate of life expectancy.
The parameters you enter are: age, Continent and gender. When I execute it, I get to enter the parameters and then it just stops working.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char gender,cont;  //cont=Continent
    char male,female,America,Oceania,Europe,Africa,Asia;
    int age,le; //le=Life expectancy
    printf("Insert Continent\n");
    scanf("%s",&cont);
    printf("Insert Gender\n");
    scanf("%s",&gender);
    printf("Insert Age\n");
    scanf("%d",&age);

    //for females
    if (gender==female) {
        if(cont==America) { 
            if(80-age<0) {
                le=80-age;
                printf("Outlived life expectancy by:\t",le);
            } else {
                le=80-age;
                printf("You are expected to live ",le," more years");
            }
        }
        if(cont==Oceania) {   
            if(80-age<0) {
                le=80-age;
                printf("Outlived life expectancy by:\t",le);
            } else {
                le=80-age;
                printf("You are expected to live ",le," more years");
            }
        }
        if(cont==Europe) {  
            if(82-age<0) {
                le=82-age;
                printf("Outlived life expectancy by:\t");
            } else {
                le=82-age;
                printf("You are expected to live ",le," more years");
            }
        }
        if(cont==Asia) {    
            if(74-age<0) {
                le=74-age;
                printf("Outlived life expectancy by:\t");
            } else {
                le=74-age;
                printf("You are expected to live ",le," more years");
            }
        }
        if(cont==Africa) {  
            if(64-age<0) {
                le=64-age;
                printf("Outlived life expectancy by:\t");
            } else {
                le=64-age;
                printf("You are expected to live ",le," more years");
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're only catching Female gender if it's male the program will exit

Comment: there is also the male part in the main program but it would be twice as long so I though I would post half of it since it is basically repeating

Comment: Is it possible the gender is case sensitive? Or do you have a menu select to make sure that doesn't happen

Comment: what is `cont==America` et al. supposed to do?

Comment: Have you set a value for the variables you compare to somewhere? I can’t see them anywhere in this code

Comment: Is there no comparison between words in C? That I did not know

Comment: Strings are not words, they can be multiple words. Also, you never define `America` anywhere. You need to either define `America` (the variable) (perhaps as `"America"`) or compare `cont` directly to the string you're testing for (again, perhaps `"America"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing entire strings in memory where you've only allocated a single character. This is a "buffer overflow" and causes undefined behavior.

Instead of allocating these as single characters (type `char`), try allocating them as arrays of characters (e.g., `unsigned char cont[128];`). I also recommend using `fgets()` for string input, instead of using `scanf()` with the `%s` specifier.

Additionally, don't use `cont == America` to compare strings. The `strcmp()` function is the right tool for this job.

Lastly, you never define the variables you're using here as constants (like `America`). You need to either define `America` (the variable) (perhaps as `"America"`) or compare `cont` directly to the string you're testing for (again, perhaps `"America"`)

```
int main(void) {
  const unsigned char *America="America";
  unsigned char cont[128];
  ...
  fgets(cont, 128, stdin);
  ...
  if (strcmp(cont, America) == 0) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```